# Requests/urllib3 Retry warning when downloading image

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm downloading some images sequentially using the following code, but am getting lots of `WARNING: Retrying` messages. It's worth noting the image url which causes this vary's every time and sometimes never happens.

```
session = requests.Session()
session.keep_alive = False
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=100, pool_maxsize=100, max_retries=3)
session.mount("http://", adapter)
session.mount("https://", adapter)

response = session.get(image_url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True, timeout=20)
```

And this causes the warning

```
2016-06-28 07:16:47 [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=20)",)': /564x/4d/75/78/4d7578cf80d146b9d2b597f8678c7b31.jpg
```

How can I fix/suppress these? It does not make sense to have lots of retry warnings in my logs. I've checkout the requests source code but I don't want to be disabling all warnings:

```
log.warning("Retrying (%r) after connection "
            "broken by '%r': %s", retries, err, url)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was trying to disable the wrong thing. I just had todo

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the *urllib3* warnings:

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

Or as the [urllib3 docs](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#within-the-code) suggest you can capture the warnings with the  `logging` module:

```
logging.captureWarnings(True)
```

You can also do it outside  the code with [PYTHONWARNINGS](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#without-modifying-code)